# Android Application doesn't read css file completely

Tags: android

> hi I have **Android** App as I embed **HTML** file , I added my code and when I test the app I noticed that some of **css** classes doesn't called as **@media** also the **JQuery** doesn't called .

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_elaraby_group);

     WebView wv=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_engine);
     wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
}
```

Comment: For the JQuery add `wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);` after you have binded the view.

Answer (score 0):

Well you have to provide exact same structure you are using in html page in your asses folder.Otherwise it will not get some files referenced in your html file.And hence those CSS and JavaScript code never gets run.So try with providing same structure as your localhost server.